# Changing schema name in OpenAPI docs generated by FastAPI

Tags: python, openapi, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using FastAPI to create backend for my project. I have a method that allows to upload a file. I implemented it as follows:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, UploadFile, File

from app.models.schemas.files import FileInResponse

router = APIRouter()


@router.post("", name="files:create-file", response_model=FileInResponse)
async def create(file: UploadFile = File(...)) -> FileInResponse:
    pass
```

As you can see, I use a dedicated pydantic model for a method result—`FileInResponse`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

from pydantic import BaseModel


class FileInResponse(BaseModel):
    path: Path
```

And I follow this naming pattern for models (naming models as `<Entity>InCreate`, `<Entity>InResponse`, and so on) throughout the API. However, I couldn't create a pydantic model with a field of the type `File`, so I had to declare it directly in the route definition (i.e. without a model containing it). As a result, I have this long auto generated name `Body_files_create_file_api_files_post` in the OpenAPI docs:

[image: Generated OpenAPI docs]

Is there a way to change the schema name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone is interested into renaming auto generated fields from FastAPI in openapi.json file, you should add an `operation_id` param to your route. This will allow FastAPI to use this id to generate a clearer attribute name for the generated schema.

Before:

```py
@router.post(
    "/{opportunity_id}/files",
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
)
async def attach_opportunity_file(
    db: Database,
    uploaded_file: UploadFile = File(title="File to upload"),
) -> OpportunityFile:
    pass
```

[image: before-fastapi-swagger]

After:

```py
@router.post(
    "/{opportunity_id}/files",
    status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
    operation_id="attach_opportunity_file",
)
async def attach_opportunity_file(
    db: Database,
    uploaded_file: UploadFile = File(title="File to upload"),
) -> OpportunityFile:
    pass
```

[image: after-fastapi-swagger]

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at response model you see [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/):

It receives the same type you would declare for a Pydantic model atribute, so it can be a Pydantic model, but it can also be, e.g. a list of Pydantic models, like List[Item].

FastAPI will use this response_model to:

```
Convert the output data to its type declaration.
Validate the data.
Add a JSON Schema for the response, in the OpenAPI path operation.
Will be used by the automatic documentation systems.
```

That mean that response model is use to return json not a file like you want to do.

> I couldn't create a pydantic model with a field of the type File

This is totaly normal

> so I had to declare it directly in the route definition (i.e. without a model containing it)

And that's normal too, remember that File is not a python type nor a pydantic specific type so it can't be part of a model inheritating from pydantic BaseModel.

To do a file response you can follow [the official doc](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

some_file_path = "large-video-file.mp4"
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    return FileResponse(some_file_path)
```

if you want to return a file like object (i.e. file from an instance of [UploadFile](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile)) follow [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#using-streamingresponse-with-file-like-objects) part of the doc:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

some_file_path = "large-video-file.mp4"
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def main():
    def iterfile():
        with open(some_file_path, mode="rb") as file_like:
            yield from file_like

    return StreamingResponse(iterfile(), media_type="video/mp4")
```